# proving divergence with $ \text{ lim inf }\frac{n*(a_{n+1}-a_n)}{a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges if $a_n$ is a sequence with $a_n>0\forall n$ and assume $lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ and $ \text{ lim inf }\frac{n*(a_{n+1}-a_n)}{a_n}>0$.

I've tried to assume $\frac{n*(a_{n+1}-a_n)}{a_n}$ is bounded, which led to a contradiction. But i'm not sure if this is correct and how to go further. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hints: There exist $c>0$ and $n_0$ such that  $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} -1 >\frac  c n$ for $n \geq n_0$. So $a_n >a_{n_0} \prod_{n=n_0}^{\infty} (1+\frac   c n)$ and $\prod_{n=n_0}^{\infty} (1+\frac   c n)=\infty$ since $\sum \frac  1 n =\infty$.